# Getting what is in between brackets from a value

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following value in a cell:

```
May 04, 2022 (50bp)
```

I need only what is in between `(` and `)`. I was thinking of using `=RIGHT()` but I never know how much is inm between the two brackets (so the number of characters I have to give as a parameter to `RIGHT()`, will differ.

What is the correct way of handling this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXEXTRACT()` function.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\((.*)\)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text between any characters, use a formula with the **MID** and **FIND** functions despite how much is in between the two brackets.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

[image]

more information [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/extract-text-between-characters-parenthesis/)